# Adding List<Object> as a variable to database using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, hsqldb

So I'm trying to add to database using JDBC with HSQLDB from files. And I need to insert the `List<Object>` as a variable into the database.

This is what it looks like as a Java object:

```
public class Plant {

    private Long id;
    private String plantName;
    private List<PlantParts> plantParts;
    ... 
}

public class PlantParts {
    private String leaves;
    private String pedicle;
    private String petals;
    ...
}
```

In folder `resources` I have a file called `insert_plant.sql` that contains this query:

```
INSERT INTO PLANTS (id, plantname, plantparts)
  VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR sequence, ?, ?);
```

And the table is generated with this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE PLANTS (
   id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   plantname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   plantparts VARCHAR(255) NULL,  //No idea what to put here
);
```

And now in Java I am calling this:

```
public static void insertIntoOrderTable(BasicDataSource basicDataSource, String plantname, List<PlantParts> plantparts) throws  SQLException{
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try {
        conn = basicDataSource.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(Util.readFileFromClasspath("insert_plant.sql"), new String[]{"id"});
        stmt.setString(1, plantname);
        stmt.setString(2, plantparts); //And no idea what to do here
        stmt.executeUpdate();


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

The requests will usually come as a JSON:

```
   { "id": 5,
     "plantName": "awesome plant",
     "plantParts":[
       {"leaves":"green","pedicle":"yellow","petals":"many"},
       {"leaves":"red","pedicle":"yellow","petals":"few"}
     ]
   }
```

My guess is that they should be held in the separate tables, but how can I do that and when I would need to get the object then how could I get it as a whole.

Comment: A list of plant parts is not a string. You can't (or at least, shouldn't) store that in a single varchar column. Instead, you should have an additional table with a column for each field of a plant part, and a foreign key to the plant it belongs to. Learn about database normalization and database design.

Comment: To add on to what @JBNizet said, you have a One to Many relationship between Plant and Plant parts. You should create a separate table and maintain that relationship.

Comment: Read about [*Object-relational impedance mismatch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch)

Comment: Did you consider just storing the JSON representation of the `plantParts` array in the `plantparts` column? That would be possible, although the relational database purists might not approve, as suggested by the first two comments above. (Also, VARCHAR(255) might not be sufficient; you may need to use CLOB instead.)

Comment: @GordThompson im trying with multiple databases at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL model of your data will be different from Java in how the Plant and PlantParts objects are linked together. In the Java model, Plant has a collection of PlantParts objects. In the SQL model, the PlantParts objects reference the Plant object.

So you need these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE plants (
   id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   plantname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE plantparts (
   id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   leaves VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   pedicles VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   petals VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   plantid BIGINT NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (plantid) REFERENCES plants(id)
);
```

Note there is no column in the `plants` table for the PlantParts objects. The data for the PlantParts in your JSON object goes into two rows of the plantparts table. The plantid column of both of these rows will contain the id of the Plant object, which is 5.